# Can you use a formula to implement the Solver, or to find a numerical solution?

Tags: excel, numerical-methods

**Is there a way to implement the Solver in a formula**, to find the zeros of a given function numerically? Or to solve an optimisation problem (root finding can be reformulated as an optimisation problem, too)?

Solver has a GUI that basically lets you solve one cell at a time.

You can automate that with VBA, but the output is still static, i.e. if the cells change, you need to run the VBA code again.

**If, instead, it could be implemented as a formula, then it would be recalculated automatically as its inputs change. Is this at all possible?**

Let me make an example with the calculation of present value and internal rate of return; yes, I know Excel has a formula to calculate that, mine is just an example.

C6:C8 are cashflows; the internal rate of return is the rate which causes the net present value of these cashflows to be zero

Is there a way to write a formula in C11 to calculate the rate that causes the target function (the NPV in C10) to be zero?

Basically something like an `fsolve()` in [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) or Python's [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)?

**The only thing I can think of is to write a UDF in VBA to implement something like a bi-section method or a Newton Rhapson algorithm to solve numerically**, but it would feel a bit like reinventing the wheel. Plus the IRR is a very simple case, but, for more complex calculations, I'm not sure VBA is the best tool. Is this the only option?

[image]

**EDIT**: It was suggested that installing the Solver AddIn makes certain [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/functions/using-the-solver-vba-functions) available in Excel, like SolverOk(). However, as far as I understand, these functions are to be used in VBA code, not to be entered into an Excel spreadhseet. Or, at least, if there is a way, I haven't found it. For example, if I use `SolverOk()` as per the syntax in the link, I get a `#Value!` error. This is after enabling the reference to Solver as explained in the link.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of functions in excel starting with the name "solver"... have you checked them?

Comment: @SolarMike , I have edited the question to reflect your point. Basically I couldn't get that to work; I believe those functions may be for VBA code only, but any comment would be more than welcome!

Comment: Have you considered "Goal Seek" in the tools menu?

Comment: @SolarMike, AFAIK goal seek, like Solver, provides a static solution, not a dynamic one like a formula would. In other words, as I change the inputs, the solution found by goal seek would not change - I'd need to re-run goal seek manually.

Comment: You mentioned you can write the formula in vba, but have to manually recalculate. You can declare it as a volatile function if you want it to recalculate automatically. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: Would you be open to using VBA?

Comment: @EEM, do you mean coding a VBA function that does the numerical solving, eg a grid search, Newton Rhapson etc, or a VBA function which calls the solver and whose output updates automatically as the inputs change?

Comment: @CBRF23, I don't think a volatile function is what I need. I don't need the function to be volatile, only to update when its inputs change.

Comment: Creating a function that calculates the expected value for any Financial, Mathematical, etc function would a huge task, as such, I believe that using solver is the best choice in excel. So I’m thinking of a kind of “dynamic” solver using VBA. Would that be an aceptable answer?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to make Solver dynamic using `Define Names` and the `Worksheet Event`

1. Using the sample provided, create the following `Names`:
   a.  `_Goal` located at `C11`
   b.  `_Input` located at `C6:C8`
   c.  `_Output` located at `C12`
   d.  `_Formula` located at `C10`
2. In the `module` of the worksheet copy the following `Worksheet Event` procedure:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rGoal As Range, rInput As Range, rOutput As Range, rFormula As Range

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       With Target.Worksheet
           Set rGoal = .Range("_Goal")
           Set rInput = .Range("_Input")
           Set rOutput = .Range("_Output")
           Set rFormula = .Range("_Formula")
           If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, rInput) Is Nothing) Then
               rOutput.ClearContents
               rFormula.GoalSeek Goal:=rGoal.Value2, ChangingCell:=rOutput
       End If: End With

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Application.EnableEvents = True

       End Sub
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, if I understand correctly: 1) associating this to Worksheet_change makes the function volatile, forcing a recalculation even when cells that are not the inputs change. This would slow down the worksheet substantially. 2) This only works with a single cell, not if I need to find a solution for, say, all the cells in a given column.

Comment: 1) It doesn’t work in the same manner as a volatile UDF. It's a `Worksheet Event` not an `UDF`, the event gets triggered when there is a change in any cell in the worksheet, however the procedure validates the changed range (`Target`) against the `_Input` range, therefore if the changes were performed outside the `_Input` range nothing happens.
2) Because you define the range `_Input` you control what cells will trigger the event, as you are concern about the performance speed I strongly suggest not to use an entire column as an input range unless you really have 1048576 changing values.

Comment: Try the suggested method and let me know any questions, concerns you might have.

Comment: The procedure as it stands now validates only the input range, but if you need it can also be adjusted in order to include the goal range in the validation.